# Is it good to run a bunch of ajax with setInterval. more than 5 ajax are running

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What is the setback on having to many ajax running. I have more than 5 setIntervals with different time to run, calling ajax, to update html or just check the session is alive. Is this good? some run every second, some every 5 minutes or so. what is the best way to do this.

Comment: the big question is 'why would you need to run so many so often?'

Comment: Generally ajax calls are pretty lightweight since they only read the output of the url. That aside: I wouldn't recommend running one every second it will soon start to add up eating bandwidth, especially in a high volume site with lots of people firing off requests every second.

Comment: @phirschybar #1 running if CI and Native Sessions are stil alive(CI tends to die alot on IE),#2 Updating a list with .html() if there are new notes available,#3 Updating another list with diffrent set of data,#4 Checking database, if new emails/messages comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally stray away from that kind of approach, rather, I would look into a push alternative or combining all of your ajax requests into one. This can lead to a server strain if this is a high traffic site. Also, if this is for someone on dialup or on a mobile device, this will most likely destroy the client's connectivity.

I don't know anything about the project, so I don't know if pushes would work, if you have a trigger that runs when new data is available, I would check out pubnub.com and look into push.

If that isn't a viable solution, I would recommend making one script that responded with all the information that your script needed, all in one request. This reduces server strain.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would have one "run loop" with a single Ajax call that does everything. In the "run loop" check to see what sort of information needs to be returned, make the Ajax call and then update. This would help with the amount of bandwidth used, especially if you have a limited amount of bandwidth per month.

Comment: How would this be any different on bandwidth than if they were separate calls? The same amount of data is being transferred?

Comment: Actually, you need to account for headers ;) This would reduce the overlap with headers.

Comment: No... they are still separate calls, with separate headers.. or are you trying to say he should include them all in one request?

Comment: All one request, "with a single Ajax call." I ran a site on a bandwidth limit for a while and it was something I had to watch. It turns out making one large AJAX call rather than smaller ones really makes a difference (depending on how often you poll).

Comment: I see, I think both suggestions are good, I will probably have to run 1 ajax call, with returns from checking session is alive,new notes,new docs uploaded,new emails/messages.